# Embedding Invision Prototype to Squarespace - Trouble Shooting

Tags: mobile, prototype, embed, squarespace, invision

I'm trying to display an Invision prototype on my portfolio and it's fine on desktop but on mobile (my iPhone X) it's glitchy and cut off. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to fix this? I tried this: https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/205204185-How-do-I-resize-an-embedded-mobile-prototype-

But all it did was make my prototype smaller on desk top with a lot of extra white space around it. And did nothing to help the mobile version.

Thanks!